# How to get the specialized type of an EStructuralFeature's getEType()?

Tags: eclipse, type-erasure, emf

I have a method where an `EStructuralFeature` comes in as a parameter. I can get the type of the feature via the method `getEType()` and get the "real" Java class via the `EType`'s `getInstanceClass()` method. So far so good. But what if this type is generic, and I want to know its special type? Unfortunately this information is gone due to Java's Type Erasure, but is there a way to achieve this by using EMF's functionality?

Answer (score 0):

`EStructuralFeature` is an interface extends to `ETypedElement`

more details here:

[http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/emf/javadoc/2.7.0/org/eclipse/emf/ecore/EStructuralFeature.html]

Comment: The link you posted is dead. But nonetheless `ETypedElement` also only defines the method `getEType` which only reveals the erased type.